# Copying a folder with Apache VFS2 causing error Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Expecting / to follow the hostname in URI

Tags: java, apache, intellij-idea

I tried copying a folder from network to a local system using apache VFS2. I added all dependency from maven given in their pom.xml. But still im getting this error "Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException:

**Expecting / to follow the hostname in URI "Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Expecting / to follow the hostname in URI "sftp://user:*******@network/opt/file.txt"**

I searched SO site, stackexchange,superuser and found this issue topic, and remedy suggested was jar missing.
Somebody please throw some light on this issue and please provide me exact list of jars to be downloaded with intellij.

Im using this code.

```
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileObject;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemOptions;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.Selectors;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.StandardFileSystemManager;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder;

import java.io.File;

/**
 * The class SFTPUtil containing uploading, downloading, checking if file exists
 * and deleting functionality using Apache Commons VFS (Virtual File System)
 * Library
 *
 * @author Ashok
 *
 */
public class SFTPUtility {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hostName = "10.2.55.66";
        String username = "user";
        String password = "password@network";

        String localFilePath = "/opt/FakeFile.txt";
        String remoteFilePath = "/opt/file.txt";
        String remoteTempFilePath = "/tmp";

        //upload(hostName, username, password, localFilePath, remoteFilePath);
        exist(hostName, username, password, remoteFilePath);
        download(hostName, username, password, localFilePath,remoteFilePath);
        //move(hostName, username, password, remoteFilePath, remoteTempFilePath);
        //delete(hostName, username, password, remoteFilePath);
    }

    /**
     * Method to upload a file in Remote server
     *
     * @param hostName
     *            HostName of the server
     * @param username
     *            UserName to login
     * @param password
     *            Password to login
     * @param localFilePath
     *            LocalFilePath. Should contain the entire local file path -
     *            Directory and Filename with \\ as separator
     * @param remoteFilePath
     *            remoteFilePath. Should contain the entire remote file path -
     *            Directory and Filename with / as separator
     */
    public static void upload(String hostName, String username, String password, String localFilePath, String remoteFilePath) {

        File file = new File(localFilePath);
        if (!file.exists())
            throw new RuntimeException("Error. Local file not found");

        StandardFileSystemManager manager = new StandardFileSystemManager();

        try {
            manager.init();

            // Create local file object
            FileObject localFile = manager.resolveFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

            // Create remote file object
            FileObject remoteFile = manager.resolveFile(createConnectionString(hostName, username, password, remoteFilePath), createDefaultOptions());
            /*
             * use createDefaultOptions() in place of fsOptions for all default
             * options - Ashok.
             */

            // Copy local file to sftp server
            remoteFile.copyFrom(localFile, Selectors.SELECT_SELF);

            System.out.println("File upload success");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            manager.close();
        }
    }

    public static boolean move(String hostName, String username, String password, String remoteSrcFilePath, String remoteDestFilePath){
        StandardFileSystemManager manager = new StandardFileSystemManager();

        try {
            manager.init();

            // Create remote object
            FileObject remoteFile = manager.resolveFile(createConnectionString(hostName, username, password, remoteSrcFilePath), createDefaultOptions());
            FileObject remoteDestFile = manager.resolveFile(createConnectionString(hostName, username, password, remoteDestFilePath), createDefaultOptions());

            if (remoteFile.exists()) {
                remoteFile.moveTo(remoteDestFile);;
                System.out.println("Move remote file success");
                return true;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Source file doesn't exist");
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            manager.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to download the file from remote server location
     *
     * @param hostName
     *            HostName of the server
     * @param username
     *            UserName to login
     * @param password
     *            Password to login
     * @param localFilePath
     *            LocalFilePath. Should contain the entire local file path -
     *            Directory and Filename with \\ as separator
     * @param remoteFilePath
     *            remoteFilePath. Should contain the entire remote file path -
     *            Directory and Filename with / as separator
     */
    public static void download(String hostName, String username, String password, String localFilePath, String remoteFilePath) {

        StandardFileSystemManager manager = new StandardFileSystemManager();

        try {
            manager.init();

            // Append _downlaod_from_sftp to the given file name.
            //String downloadFilePath = localFilePath.substring(0, localFilePath.lastIndexOf(".")) + "_downlaod_from_sftp" + localFilePath.substring(localFilePath.lastIndexOf("."), localFilePath.length());

            // Create local file object. Change location if necessary for new downloadFilePath
            FileObject localFile = manager.resolveFile(localFilePath);

            // Create remote file object
            FileObject remoteFile = manager.resolveFile(createConnectionString(hostName, username, password, remoteFilePath), createDefaultOptions());

            // Copy local file to sftp server
            localFile.copyFrom(remoteFile, Selectors.SELECT_SELF);

            System.out.println("File download success");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            manager.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to delete the specified file from the remote system
     *
     * @param hostName
     *            HostName of the server
     * @param username
     *            UserName to login
     * @param password
     *            Password to login
     * @param localFilePath
     *            LocalFilePath. Should contain the entire local file path -
     *            Directory and Filename with \\ as separator
     * @param remoteFilePath
     *            remoteFilePath. Should contain the entire remote file path -
     *            Directory and Filename with / as separator
     */
    public static void delete(String hostName, String username, String password, String remoteFilePath) {
        StandardFileSystemManager manager = new StandardFileSystemManager();

        try {
            manager.init();

            // Create remote object
            FileObject remoteFile = manager.resolveFile(createConnectionString(hostName, username, password, remoteFilePath), createDefaultOptions());

            if (remoteFile.exists()) {
                remoteFile.delete();
                System.out.println("Delete remote file success");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            manager.close();
        }
    }

    // Check remote file is exist function:
    /**
     * Method to check if the remote file exists in the specified remote
     * location
     *
     * @param hostName
     *            HostName of the server
     * @param username
     *            UserName to login
     * @param password
     *            Password to login
     * @param remoteFilePath
     *            remoteFilePath. Should contain the entire remote file path -
     *            Directory and Filename with / as separator
     * @return Returns if the file exists in the specified remote location
     */
    public static boolean exist(String hostName, String username, String password, String remoteFilePath) {
        StandardFileSystemManager manager = new StandardFileSystemManager();

        try {
            manager.init();

            // Create remote object
            FileObject remoteFile = manager.resolveFile(createConnectionString(hostName, username, password, remoteFilePath), createDefaultOptions());

            System.out.println("File exist: " + remoteFile.exists());

            return remoteFile.exists();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            manager.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generates SFTP URL connection String
     *
     * @param hostName
     *            HostName of the server
     * @param username
     *            UserName to login
     * @param password
     *            Password to login
     * @param remoteFilePath
     *            remoteFilePath. Should contain the entire remote file path -
     *            Directory and Filename with / as separator
     * @return concatenated SFTP URL string
     */
    public static String createConnectionString(String hostName, String username, String password, String remoteFilePath) {
        if(remoteFilePath.startsWith("/")||remoteFilePath.startsWith("\\"))
                remoteFilePath=remoteFilePath.substring(1);
        return "sftp://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + hostName + "/" + remoteFilePath;
    }

    /**
     * Method to setup default SFTP config
     *
     * @return the FileSystemOptions object containing the specified
     *         configuration options
     * @throws FileSystemException
     */
    public static FileSystemOptions createDefaultOptions() throws FileSystemException {
        // Create SFTP options
        FileSystemOptions opts = new FileSystemOptions();

        // SSH Key checking
        SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setStrictHostKeyChecking(opts, "no");

        /*
         * Using the following line will cause VFS to choose File System's Root
         * as VFS's root. If I wanted to use User's home as VFS's root then set
         * 2nd method parameter to "true"
         */
        // Root directory set to user home
        SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserDirIsRoot(opts, false);

        // Timeout is count by Milliseconds
        SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setTimeout(opts, 10000);

        return opts;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please specify the file location as following and check

If it is local file,

```
file:///home/someuser/somedir       
file:///C:/DocumentsandSettings     
file://///somehost/test/text.xml
```

Or if it is ftp,

```
> ftp://myusername:mypassword@hostname/test/test.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

Your password has "@".

You need escape, try replace "@" to "%40".

Answer (score 0):

Your *password* contains a `@`, thus concatenation creates an invalid connection string: `sftp://username:p@ssword@hostName`

It must be encoded as `sftp://username:p%40ssword@hostName`

Instead of concatenation, create a `java.net.URI` to handle proper *password* encoding

```
String userInfo = user + ":" + passwd;
URI uri = new URI("sftp", userInfo, host, -1, path, null, null);
```

Detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29568361/912046